# Disappearing model when rotating

Tags: modeling, vertices

How do I stop model from disappearing when I rotate around it? It happens randomly and I don't know how to fix it. Example would be today when I was in edit mode i selected vertices and when i rotated it started to disappear. The model lost all textures and when I switched back to object mode the whole thing was invisible.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Sounds like your model is larger than the max draw distance. Look at this image of mine to get an understanding of what I mean:

https://imgur.com/a/7zKibUj

Comment: Or it could be that the object is one sided with no backface, or that the normals are flipped... but without more information  is hard to tell.

Comment: .. As people have already said, less directly this is almost certainly a question of adjusting the viewport depth clipping.  In 3D View,, In 2.79 .. N.. Properties region, View panel.   In 2.8, .. N, Properties region, View tab... 'Clip Start.. Clip End'